# Unable to do USB passthrough with QEMU

Tags: linux, usb, virtual-machine, qemu

I have installed virt-mananager and QEMU

`sudo apt-get -y install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin bridge-utils virt-manager;`

I also installed

`sudo apt-get install libusb-dev`

`sudo apt-get install libusbredirparser-dev`

When I add a USB mouse with QEMU graphically by clicking add hardware, selecting USB host and selecting the keyboard.

The error I get when booting is

Error starting domain: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2017-06-30T11:24:52.687627Z qemu-system-x86_64: -device usb-host,hostbus=1,hostaddr=4,id=hostdev0,bus=usb.0,port=2: failed to find host usb device 1:4

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 90, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 126, in tmpcb
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/libvirtobject.py", line 83, in newfn
    ret = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/domain.py", line 1402, in startup
    self._backend.create()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 1035, in create
    if ret == -1: raise libvirtError ('virDomainCreate() failed', dom=self)
libvirtError: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2017-06-30T11:24:52.687627Z qemu-system-x86_64: -device usb-host,hostbus=1,hostaddr=4,id=hostdev0,bus=usb.0,port=2: failed to find host usb device 1:4

Any ideas for how to fix this?
Also if I remove the USB host the VM boots normally.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I didn't find a solution.